# Scala - Check If object exist inside a list

Tags: scala

I'm trying to write an algorithm to check if an object exists inside a list.

My case class is the following:

```
case class Person(id:Int, name:String, friends:List[Person] = Nil)
```

I've wrote it using this code:

```
@tailrec
final def find(id: Int, tree: List[Person]):Option[Person] = tree match {
  case Nil => None
  case (h :: t) => if(h.id == id) Option(h) else find(key, t ::: h.friends)
}
```

Is it a good approach? Use tail recursive and append another list on tail list? If not, what would be the best approach?

Comment: Think what will happen when you have friends of friends: `eve -> [john, anne], anne -> [peter, lois], peter -> [eve, bob, russ]`

Comment: It will loop the entire list. And i can stop after first friend have a friend. If i'm looking for "peter" i could stop just after find him on Anne list

Comment: Since nothing ensures that you indeed have a tree (and not a graph with cycles), you should remove duplicates from the appended list. Once you have done this, your algorithm just implements a width-first search on your tree, you cannot do much better.

Comment: If you don't remove cycles, you will have an infinite loop whenever you search for an inexistant person.

Comment: Got it! Thank you!

Comment: why not use filter?

Comment: filter mapping children for each object?

Answer (score 0):

I ended up with the following implementation which basically *tail recursive BFS*:

```
@tailrec
def find(id: Int, level: List[Person], visited: Set[Person] = Set.empty): Option[Person] =
  if (level.isEmpty) None
  else {
    // Try to find person on this level
    val found = level.find(_.id == id).filterNot(visited.contains)
    if (found.isDefined) found
    else find(
      id,
      // Next level construction
      level.flatMap(_.friends).distinct,
      // Keep track of visited to handle cycles
      visited ++ level
    )
  }
```

**UPDATE:** Also, I would suggest to add call by name to be able to play around with more test cases:

```
class Person(val id: Int, val name: String, friends: => List[Person]) {

  def friendList = friends

  override def toString = name
}

object Person {

  def apply(id: Int, name: String, friends: => List[Person] = Nil) = new Person(id, name, friends)
}
```

In that case you can compose the example from the comments:

```
val john = Person(1, "john")
val russ = Person(2, "russ")
val bob = Person(3, "bob")
val lois = Person(5, "lois")

lazy val `eve friends` = List(john, anne)
lazy val `peter friends` = List(eve, bob, russ)
lazy val `anne friends` = List(peter, lois)

val eve = Person(7, "eve", `eve friends`)
val peter = Person(8, "peter", `peter friends`)
val anne: Person = Person(6, "anne", `anne friends`)

println(find(8, List(eve, peter, lois))) // result: Some(peter)
```